# Extracting lower and upper limit of a range of values based on a multiplier

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I am trying to find an optimal way to get the min and max limits from a list of lists provided a multiplier. I've tried two methods and I'm wondering if there is a more optimal solution that scales better in terms of performance when executed multiple times.

```
import timeit

def get_lower_upper_limits(inps):
    ranges, multipliers = inps
    min_l = 0
    max_l = 0
    for idx, multiplier in enumerate(multipliers):
        min_l += multiplier * (min(ranges[idx]) if multiplier > 0 else max(ranges[idx]))
        max_l += multiplier * (max(ranges[idx]) if multiplier > 0 else min(ranges[idx]))
    return min_l, max_l

def wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrapped():
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

ranges = [[1000, 1400, 1800], [2200, 2400, 2600], [3000, 3100, 3200]]
multiplier = [-1, 2, 3]
assert len(ranges) == len(multiplier)
wrapped = wrapper(get_lower_upper_limits, (ranges, multiplier))
print('get_lower_upper_limits: {}'.format(timeit.timeit(wrapped, number=5000000)))
```

get_lower_upper_limits: 9.775336363000001

Example:

range = [[1000, 1500, 2000], [2000, 2500, 3000]]

multiplier = [1, 2]

range_after_multiplication = [[1000, 1500, 2000], [4000, 5000, 6000]]

The min/max limit (or number) that can be produced from the sum of each of the elements in the list is:

min_l = 1000 + 4000 = 5000

max_l = 2000 + 6000 = 8000

Comment: @superbrain added an example, I hope it's clearer now

Comment: Seems inefficient to search for min and max in the ranges. They're all sorted, so just take the first and last element.

Comment: this combined with the changes in the answer below help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Function Arguments

```py
def get_lower_upper_limits(inps):
    ranges, multipliers = inps
    ...
```

This is a curious choice for declaring arguments to the function.  You must package two arguments together as a tuple for the `inps` argument, without any clear indication to the caller of the requirement.

Why not declare the function as:

```py
def get_lower_upper_limits(ranges, multipliers):
    ...
```

The caller then has a clue that the function takes two arguments, a `ranges` and a `multipliers`.

A `"""docstring"""` could go a long way towards helping the caller understand the requirements for calling the function.  Type-hints would go even further.  I recommend researching both subjects.

## Wrapper

With the above change to the function arguments, your `wrapped` function will need a new definition:

```py
wrapped = wrapper(get_lower_upper_limits, (ranges, multiplier))
```

This presently provides 1 argument (the `tuple` created with `(ranges, multiplier)`) to be passed to the function being wrapped.  With the above change, the function now needs the `ranges` and `multiplier` passed as individual arguments:

```py
wrapped = wrapper(get_lower_upper_limits, ranges, multiplier)
```

## Wrapper-free packaging

The `wrapper` function is not needed.

First, the `partial` function from `functools` will perform the wrapping for you (and provides additional capabilities, which are not needed here).  Remove the `wrapper` function, and replace it with an import:

```py
from functools import partial

wrapped = partial(get_lower_upper_limits, ranges, multiplier)
```

This may be faster than your hand-written `wrapper` function, as built-ins can be implemented directly in C.

Again, as this is not using the full capabilities of `partial`, a simpler alternative exists:

```py
wrapped = lambda: get_lower_upper_limits(ranges, multiplier)
```

## Don't index

In Python, indexing is relatively slow.  If you do not need `idx`, except for use in `variable[idx]`, it is best to loop over `variable` directly.

Since in this case, you need to loop over two lists `ranges` and `multipliers` simultaneously, you'll need to `zip` them together first (zip as in zipper, not as in compression).

```py
    for values, multiplier in zip(ranges, multipliers):
        min_l += multiplier * (min(values) if multiplier > 0 else max(values))
        ...
```

## Improved code

```py
import timeit

def get_lower_upper_limits(ranges, multipliers):
    min_l = 0
    max_l = 0
    for values, multiplier in zip(ranges, multipliers):
        min_l += multiplier * (min(values) if multiplier > 0 else max(values))
        max_l += multiplier * (max(values) if multiplier > 0 else min(values))
    return min_l, max_l

ranges = [[1000, 1400, 1800], [2200, 2400, 2600], [3000, 3100, 3200]]
multiplier = [-1, 2, 3]
assert len(ranges) == len(multiplier)
func = lambda: get_lower_upper_limits(ranges, multiplier)

print('get_lower_upper_limits: {}'.format(timeit.timeit(func, number=500000)))
```

Approximately 5% faster